# Install phalcon on osx

Tags: php, macos, xampp, phalcon

I did everything described here (for OS X)
https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/install.html#mac-os-x
https://phalconphp.com/en/download

I also added `extension=phalcon.so` to the php.ini and restarted the webserver.
I copied the compiled lib to `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions`

But when I search for "phalcon" in phpinfo there is no entry, so phalocn was not installed.
Has anyone an idea what I can do to fix this problem?

PS: I use xampp as web server (PHP Version 5.5).

Comment: Make sure the php.ini you added extension.phalcon.so is the same that shows up on phpInfo().

It happens quite often that you have PHP installed twice on diferent locations

Comment: @Borjante I'm sure it is the right .ini-file

Comment: Do the extensions shown in phpInfo() match with al the .so files in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions